# how to block the command "clEnqueueFillImage",which don't have the blocking argument?

Tags: opencl, blocking, enqueue

In the source code of funciton "clEnqueueFillImage",it want to blocking the command but I don't figure out how to blocking it without the blocking argument?

````
{
     iResult = OCL_Flush(psCommandQueue);
     if (iResult != CL_SUCCESS)
     {
          PVR_DPF((PVR_DBG_ERROR, "Failed implicit flush before blocking write."));
          goto exit;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`clEnqueueFillImage`, like many other functions in OpenCL, has and event out parameter. From the documentation:

> Returns an event object that identifies this particular write
> command and can be used to query or queue a wait for this particular
> command to complete. event can be NULL in which case it will not be
> possible for the application to query the status of this command or
> queue a wait for this command to complete.

So you could simply use the returned event:

```
cl_event sync_event{};
CL_CHECK_ERROR(clEnqueueFillImage(... , &sync_event);
CL_CHECK_ERROR(clWaitForEvents(1, &sync_event));
```

Comment: It seems work in logic, but in souce coude, OCL_GetAppHints()->bBlockingEnqueues can't be set TRUE by driver.